# Get rid of sub menu in Java Swing using Windows builder

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I am trying to learn Java Swing and Windows Builder by creating a personal project. I added a menu bar File, Edit, View, Help etc. When I click on 'File' I get Open,Save,Save As. This is also correct. But using the default options in Windows Builder, Gives me a sub menu under 'Open' indicated by an arrow but I don't want this all I want is:

File
- Open
- Save
- Save As

And I want to get rid of

File
- Open ->NULL (this is what comes as default in Windows builder)

Comment: Please post SSCCE if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You probably added an "Open" `JMenu`, instead of adding an "Open" `JMenuItem`. The source code would confirm it.

`JMenuItem` is a leaf in the menu tree. `JMenu` is a container for other `JMenu`s and `JMenuItem`s.